# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I know such questions are in ton in SO but my situation seems little weird to me.

I have a `textbox` with a calendar extender control on my aspx page

Default format is "d" in extenders date format property.
When I choose my date say `15th May 2012` from the calendar,it gives me `5/15/2012`, which is fine.

Since its a string and my db field is oftype datetime, so I am using

```
Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox.Text);   // TextBox.Text = 5/15/2012
```

But it throws the exception, 
`string was not recognized as valid datetime`.

I then Change the code and used `DateTime.Parse()` but the issue remains. Then i tried to reformat the date something like this,

```
Convert.ToDateTime(string.Format("0:MM-dd-yyyy",TextBox.Text)).Date
```

but still its throwing exceptions..

Please help me.

Comment: I've formatted your question, *kindly* try to use paragraphs and line breaks on your next question, as people won't bother to read them if they look like a pile of junk text

Comment: @shai - thanks... +1 for this. Actually posted question from Samsung Galaxy Tab, so no more scopes like laptops...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *suppose* that your dev machine date-time format is not equal to MM/DD/YYYY, but something else (for example DD/MM/YYYY). Have a look on your computer Regional settings to see your system date time format.

Comment: How to remove this dependency... i think Shai's solution seems close as he is using CultureInfo...

Comment: Also , what if my live has MM/dd/yyyy.. Do i need to change the code or change my regional settings till developmentmwnt...

Comment: @AmitRanjan: if you want to remove a dependency from `datetime` format (but this is valid also for any other format too) you should define for your application a single valid format (could be `invartiant` like Shai suggests, could be any other) and maintain it. There is no easy solution for this, especially when you're going to maintain  files/data that comes from other systems which are not mandatory has the same format and *can not* be converted to desirable one (legacy systems for example)

Answer (score 4):

Use the following,

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", 
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

There's probably a difference between your system's DateTime format and the DateTiem format the extender uses.